# ColdFusion gives error on CFSET Bad File Exception

Tags: coldfusion, bluedragon

I have been running into this issue with a coldfusion site I am trying to migrate to my hosting plan.  I keep seeing this when I bring up the index file:

```
Bad File Exception 
Request /index.cfm 



Type Template 
Message Expression Error 
Position Line=166; Column=25 
Detail Problem occurred while parsing: count++ 
Extended Info Encountered "<EOF>". Was expecting one of:         
<FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ... "-" ... "+" ... "#" ... "(" ... 
   <IDENTIFIER> ... "DOES" ... "CONTAIN" ... "GREATER" ... "THAN" ... "LESS" ... "VAR" ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <STRING_LITERAL> ... <BOOLEAN_LITERAL> ... "NULL" ...  

Source 163:                       </li>
164:                     </ul><!--end social-->
165:                   </section><!--end column-->
166:                   <cfset count++> <-- that is where the error happens
167:                 </cfoutput>
^ Snippet from underlying CFML source enter code here
```

BlueDragon Time @ Server: 04:29:08.223 Tuesday, 3 March 2015

I really do not know what is wrong so if someone could please help me that would be awesome.  Any suggestions would be great at this point.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you migrating from Adobe ColdFusion to BlueDragon?

Comment: If yes, you can change your line 166 to <cfset count=count+1>

Comment: And, if yes, why choose BlueDragon over Railo or Lucee?

Comment: Are you developing in ColdFusion for a BlueDragon host?  Bad idea.  Differences between development and production software leads to these types of problems.  It's not just software.  Developing in later versions than what's in production is equally problematic.

Comment: Not developing it, only hosting it while I move them to WordPress.  As I say I am very new to ColdFusion.

Comment: Ok, that got me a bit further along, now I have another error:

Comment: Type Database 
Detail The datasource thenightclub could not be found or was invalid 
Extended Info javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name thenightclub is not bound in this Context

Comment: How do I marked the question as answered?  CFML-Developer's comment got me running.

Comment: Why would you choose BlueDragon over Railo or Lucee? Teh latter 2 would likely have very few issues running existing code. The former...as this question shows, will have issues with even basic code.

Comment: You can mark the question as answered when someone answers it.  The people here tend to be honourable and will probably wait for @CFML_Developer to take the hint and post his idea as an answer.  If he doesn't within a day or so, you can post your own answer and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<cfset count++>
```

Above syntax may not be valid in BlueDragon. You can change it to more generic, which is supported by all major CFML engines.

```
<cfset count = count+1>
```